# hierarchy in joining relation tables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, relational-database

I was wondering if there is any manner to utilize a feature similar to hierarchical indexing, but within the data of a pandas table.  I am interested in combining several dataframes together into one dataframe, wherein a few of the dataframes have multiple entries for one ID in the other dataframe.

As always, it is better just to show the structure.
Here is a simplified dataframe 1:

```
>>> df1
   id             txt
0   0      first sent
1   1     another one
2   2     I think you
3   3  will like this
4   4       will work
```

While dataframe 2 may have several attributes corresponding to each entry (by index ID) of dataframe 1:

```
>>> df2
   attr  id
0  chem   0
1   dis   0
2  chem   1
3  chem   1
4  chem   2
5   dis   2
6   dis   3
7   dis   3
8   dis   4
9  chem   4
```

So attempting this:

```
import pandas as pd
id = range(0,5)
texts =  ['first sent', 'another one', 'I think you', 'will like this']
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt':texts, 'id':id})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'attr':['chem', 'dis', 'chem', 'chem', 'chem', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'chem'] ,'id':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})
```

Which when merged simply provides:

```
>>> df.merge(df2, on='id')
   id             txt  attr
0   0      first sent  chem
1   0      first sent   dis
2   1     another one  chem
3   1     another one  chem
4   2     I think you  chem
5   2     I think you   dis
6   3  will like this   dis
7   3  will like this   dis
8   4       will work   dis
9   4       will work  chem
```

Now you can see that the 'txt' column is duplicated - which in this case IMO is unnecessary, and can cause some serious issues with memory if the attributes per id in `df2` are numerous.  It's possible that you could have (in this case) textual data duplicated thousands of times larger than what is required to represent the data as two separate dataframes.

I thought about trying to make the 'txt' column an index for hierarchical indexing (although I'm sure that is completely the wrong design consideration), but even still the duplication is present.

```
>>> df.merge(df2, on='id').set_index(['id', 'txt'])
                   attr
id txt                 
0  first sent      chem
   first sent       dis
1  another one     chem
   another one     chem
2  I think you     chem
   I think you      dis
3  will like this   dis
   will like this   dis
4  will work        dis
   will work       chem
```

Is there a way around this that stores the information in a single dataframe?

Comment: Hi @chase - if one of the answers below has solved your question, can you mark it when you get chance?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Tai basically similar to the last output from `df.merge(df2, on='id').set_index(['id', 'txt'])` is what I was looking for, but without the duplicated `text`.  Also, the ability to have this behavior without making `text` an index (string indices are frowned upon I've heard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option is more memory efficient. The reason is that you will end up with a multi-index and the actual text values are not duplicated in memory. They are only shown as duplicate in the output representation. You can see the lack of duplication if you look at the output of `merge_2.index` for your actual DataFrames.

**Demo:**

```
# I've added some extra dummy text to show how this works with larger strings
extra_txt = ",".join([str(i) for i in range(5000)])

import pandas as pd
id = range(0,5)
texts =  [
    'first sent' + extra_txt, 
    'another one' + extra_txt,
    'I think you' + extra_txt,
    'will like this' + extra_txt,
    'will work' + extra_txt,
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt':texts, 'id':id})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'attr':['chem', 'dis', 'chem', 'chem', 'chem', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'chem']     ,'id':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})

merge_1 = df.merge(df2, on='id')
merge_2 = df.merge(df2, on='id').set_index(['id', 'txt'])
```

**Version 1 memory usage:**

```
In []: merge_1.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum()
Out[]: 240335
```

**Version 2 memory usage:**

```
In []: merge_2.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum()
Out[]: 120565
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't realize that it was doing this behind the scenes already.  It still bothers me to use a string as an index, but I suppose for the hierarchical ability of the data to be realized, it's an understandable requirement.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a memory efficient solution which uses `pandas` [categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). The cost is now just an integer for each value in 'txt' column in the result, which is significantly cheaper than storing text strings.

```
import pandas as pd

ids = range(0,4)
texts =  ['first sent', 'another one', 'I think you', 'will like this']

df = pd.DataFrame({'txt':texts, 'id':ids})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'attr':['chem', 'dis', 'chem', 'chem', 'chem', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'dis', 'chem'] ,'id':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})

# convert to category codes and store mapping
df['txt'] = df['txt'].astype('category')
df_txt_cats = dict(enumerate(df['txt'].cat.categories))
df['txt'] = df['txt'].cat.codes

# perform merge - memory efficinet since result only uses integers
df_merged = df.merge(df2, on='id')

# rename categories from integers to text strings from previously stored mapping
df_merged['txt'] = df_merged['txt'].astype('category')
df_merged['txt'].cat.categories = list(map(df_txt_cats.get, df_merged['txt'].cat.categories))

df_merged.dtypes
# id         int32
# txt     category
# attr      object
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice, this appears to be more efficient in memory usage for the final DataFrame also. Using yours, `df_merged.memory_usage(deep=True, index=True).sum()` gives `1094`, where my version of the original gives `1120` for the equivalent.

Comment: A side effect is merge / sort operations should be more efficient, since the dataframe picks up more efficiently which values are equivalent from the integer keys. I haven't tested this myself, but it would be a good exercise to test how well `pandas` have implemented categories.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really interesting and wonderful idea.  It appears that this still stores two separate objects in order to get the mapping of text to mapping integer, which is similar to the beginning two dataframes, but it's a nice comment on something that I was not aware of.